# The requested path Access is Denied

Tags: php, apache, access-denied

How can I implement the following behaviour in my apache server?

Visiting **[www.google.com/images/sample.png](http://www.google.com/images/sample.png)**, it shows the image. But if I go to the directory ***[www.google.com/images/](http://www.google.com/images/)*** it shows ***access denied***.

Comment: Apache has a setting to turn directory browsing on and off. You can easily find out more with some simple searching online.

Comment: @ADyson I got it in .htaccess file add -Indexes it shows "Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected." and another method is to comment LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so in httpd.conf it shows "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." ***BUT I NEED TO ADD MY OWN CUSTOM ACCESS DENIED PAGE ***

Comment: that's a separate question, then. And there may already be solutions to that online again, if you search. I would be astonished if you are the first person to have such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

In .htaccess file add -Indexes it shows "Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected."

and another method is to comment LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.

So in httpd.conf it shows "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."